# Test Case WIT in TFS2012 giving error - Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.InvalidWorkItemTypeException

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I am trying to add/import a new work item type "Test Case" (exported from MSF for agile ver 6.2 process template) into one of our existing team project based on MSF Agile 4.2 process template. I am able to import the WIT using power tools successfully. But when I try to create a new work item in team project using this Test Case template, I get the following error in tabs 'Steps' and 'Associated Automation':

*Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.InvalidWorkItemTypeException: The following work item type is not valid: Test Case. You must specify a valid work item type that belongs to a category with reference name Microsoft.TestCaseCategory or Microsoft.SharedStepCategory.
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestManagementTeamProject.CreateFromWorkItem(WorkItem workItem)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Controls.TestStepsPart.GetTestBase(WorkItem workItem)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Controls.TestStepsPart.get_TestBase()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Controls.TestStepsPart.set_WorkItemDatasource(Object value)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Controls.BasicWorkitemCustomControl.set_WorkItemDatasource(Object value)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WpfControls.CustomContentControl.set_WorkItemDatasource(Object value)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WpfControls.WorkItemControl.ControlFactory_ControlCreated(Object sender, ControlCreatedEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WpfControls.WpfControlFactory.OnControlCreated(ControlCreatedEventArgs args)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WpfControls.WpfControlFactory.CreateControl(String fieldName, String preferredControlType, String fallbackControlType, StringDictionary properties)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WpfControls.WpfFormRenderer.CreateControl(FormElement element)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WpfControls.WpfFormRenderer.RenderCollection(Grid panel, FormElementCollection collection, Int32& currentCol)*

Any idea how to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the part definition of relating to Steps / Associated Automation?

Comment: 'Steps' and 'Associated Automation' are the two tabs present in the work item screen of WIT 'Test Case'. When I click on any of those tabs, I can see only the above mentioned errors and No other user controls are loaded on those two tabs.

Answer (score 0):

By defining a default work item type for a category, you can help use the correct field population when you work in other Team Foundation clients, such as Microsoft Test Manager. By selecting the default work item defined for a category, many other fields can be auto-populated with default contents.

You modify the categories defined for a team project by modifying the XML definition file for its categories.

I updated the WIT category (given below) and imported the same (using witadmin importcategories command) to my team project. It solved the WI error!

```
<CATEGORY name="Test Case Category" refname="Microsoft.TestCaseCategory">
<DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Test Case" />
</CATEGORY>
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to clarify Jimmy's answer.  After you have created a new WIT template, identify the name that you have assigned to the template. If you are using VS Power Tools, the name you need is the Name entry box in the Work Item Type viewer.  If you have an xml file with the template, the name id /Witd:WITD/WORKITEMTYPE/@name.(For this answer, we will assume a name of "My Custom Test Case") You must now retrieve the category file to add your new template.  Do this with the witadmin exportcategories command (e.g. witadmin exportcategories /collection:"http: //tfsServerName:port/tfs/collectionPath" /p:project /f:Collections.xml which saves the collections file to the directory you run the command from).  Once you have exported the collections file, find the category you would like to add your template to or create a new category.  Next add a WORKITEMTYPE with an attribute name and a value of the template name.  Below you can see the value for a custom test case that has been added to the TestCaseCategory: 

    
    
  
After the necessary modifications, save the Collections.xml file and import it back into the server using witadmin importcategories (e.g. witadmin importcategories /collection:"http: //tfsServerName:port/tfs/collectionPath" /p:project /f:Collections.xml)
You should now be able to use the template you created to create new workitems.